# javascript single input separate into two inputs then post

Tags: javascript

java-script single input separate into two.
The first input is only 4 characters that called username and other password

```
<form action="a.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
<label for="textfield">Prepaid Code</label>
<input type="text" name="prepaid" id="prepaid" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="document.getElementById('#prepaid').substring(0,4);"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" value="document.getElementById('#prepaid').substring(4);"/>
<button onclick="document.getElementById("myform").submit()">SUBMIT</button>
```

How to make coding this by java script only

Comment: Why? Using a password `<input>` prevents the users from seeing their own user-name. And I don't see how this is beneficial in any way, or preferable over having two dedicated `<input>` elements. Further to all that, though, where did you get stuck, how far did you get when you attempted to write this yourself?

Comment: You can try using the `substr` method on the string.

Comment: Use two inputs, one for the username named `user` and the other for the password named `pass`.

Comment: it is wifi billing management user name and password need to login but i want to use like voucher code. may understand me and the software only run java web script

Comment: And how does that affect or create the problem you're asking us to solve for you?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's been thought out well. Also the example you gave have is in PHP, but you're asking for JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have got answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function vowcher(){
var prepaid = document.getElementById('prepaid').value;
var user1 = prepaid.substring(0,4);
var pass1 = prepaid.substring(4);

document.getElementById('user').value =user1;
document.getElementById('pass').value =pass1;
document.getElementById("myform").submit()
}
</script>


<form action="a.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform">
<label for="textfield">Prepaid Code</label>
<input type="text" name="prepaid" id="prepaid" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" />
<input type="hidden" name="pass" id="pass" />
<button onclick="vowcher()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that what you are describing sounds like a bad idea. Whatever you are planning can probably be accomplished in a better way. Splitting a string in the way you described is accomplished easily with [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
let user = document.getElementById('#userpass').substring(0,4);
let password = document.getElementById('#userpass').substring(4);
```

EDIT:
It looks like you just need PHP.

```
$user = substr($_POST['prepaid'], 0, 4);
$pass = substr($_POST['prepaid'], 4);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for ajax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: It looks to me like you don't need JS at all. From the *post result* part of your question, it looks like you're using PHP. Just use that. 

`$user = substr($_POST["user"], 0, 4);`